# How can I use ?,&,= symbols in Oracle ORDS 18.2 URI Template?

Tags: oracle-apex, custom-url, oracle-ords

Can I use ?,&, = symbols in Oracle APEX ORDS 18.2 version services URLs?
The system shows me.URI Template may contain only alphabetic, numeric, underscore, dash, period, and forward slash characters, or may contain a single trailing asterisk. I can I use custom URL type?

[image]

Comment: **URI Template may contain only alphabetic, numeric, underscore, dash, period, and forward slash characters** sounds quite specific to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer is you can't use them to define a URI template.  The query string  does not need to be defined all params are auto converted to binds.

For example: Calling /hr/employees/?ename=SMITH the uri template doesn't need the '?name='. That is auto added to being a bind. In the sql/plsql the code can just reference :ename

Here's a screen shot of the example  >>

[image]